# List of input values for a Single Input parameter Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote a stored procedure that takes a single input parameter and will provide multiple output parameter values by running through the stored procedure. But I'm trying to send a list of input values that goes through the logic and will present there respective outputs instead of one-on-one input.

I have created a temp table in the code section for this question but in reality I have a table available on the database and I want to take inputs (specified column) from that table (As shown below selecting `Candidate_Name` from `#Temp1`) and feed my stored procedure, so that it will retrieve other details of each Input parameter for that huge list.

```
/************ Table Creation ****************/
CREATE TABLE #TEMP1 
(
    Candidate_Name VARCHAR(20),
    Age INT,
    Designation VARCHAR(20) 
)

INSERT INTO #TEMP1 VALUES 
('Smith',   18 , 'Staff Accountant'),
('Williams',32 , 'Sr. Software Engineer'),
('Weinberg',40,  'Human Resource Manger'),
('Franklin',35,  'Operations Manager'),
('Armstrong',22, 'Database Administrator'),
('Cromley', 30,  'Recruting Manager'),
('Richardson',33,'Safety Clerk'),
('Horton', 45,   'Accounting Manager'),
('Washington',22,'HelpDesk Technician')
GO

/************ End of Table Creation ****************/

/************ Stored Procedure **************/
CREATE PROC [Employee_Details] 
    (@Name Varchar(20)) 
AS
    DECLARE @AGE INT,
            @Designation VARCHAR(20)

    SELECT AGE, Designation 
    FROM #TEMP1
    WHERE Candidate_Name = @Name

/************ End of Stored Procedure **************/

/************ Execution of Stored Procedure **************/
CREATE TABLE #TEMP2 (Employee_Name VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO #TEMP2
    SELECT Candidate_Name 
    FROM #TEMP1 

EXEC [Employee_Details] Employee_Name 

DROP TABLE #TEMP1
DROP TABLE #TEMP2
```

By doing this way, my stored procedure is taking `Employee_Name` as an input argument / parameter and returning `NULL`, which instead I want to parse the complete list of `Candidate_Names` in the `#Temp1` table and retrieve their information in one shot.

I think the way that I'm feeding the stored procedure is wrong and if someone suggest ideas that will be great.

Comment: Use a [Table Valued Parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Why the stored procedure and second table? Why not a Table-Valued User-Defined Function?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
CREATE FUNCTION <schema>.fn_Get_Employee_Details
             (@Name VARCHAR(60) = NULL) 
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(SELECT t.Candidate_Name AS Employee_Name,
        t.Age,
        t.Designation
 FROM   abrechnung.test4 AS t
 WHERE  @Name IS NULL
        OR t.Candidate_Name = @Name)
GO
```

SELECT:

```
SELECT * FROM <schema>.fn_Get_Employee_Details('Weinberg') -- DEFAULT = NULL -> all entries
```

Result:

```
Employee_Name   Age     Designation
Weinberg        40      Human Resource Manger
```

If this is not your expected output please write me what you want exactly.